# Spring XD and Oracle RDBMS

Tags: spring-xd

I am newbie to Spring XD. I have a requirement to parse a file in a specific directory and push the output in oracle table. 
Can I achieve that in Spring XD?
If not directly, can I create Spring boot/integration/batch application and deploy the same on Sprig XD?

Thanks,
Pratik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the inputs folks!

Well, I have learned **Spring Batch framework** and I am building the tasklets to manage my workflow to support my usecase. 
Further, I am The resultant Jar of Spring Batch app to SpringXD as a Custom Module and scheduled it for a daily run.

I learnt from the research on this usecase that SpringXD is superset of and includes **Spring Batch, Integration and Boot** frameworks respectively; so 
I kept the involvement of **SpringXD** as limited to Scheduling a batch job by adding custom module.

Thanks a lot for your support. 
Cheers & Happy Architecting, 
Pratik

Comment: Yes, you are right, it does includes Batch, Integration, and Boot. But from what I viewed, it is more a platform than a superset. you can deploy your modules on it, you can use its modules to realize your design, and what's more, it is distributed system.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to deploy an `ETL` process on SpringXD.
Yes, this is possible, in fact, I once worked on that.
Spring Integration is ok with springXD and the things you should do is to adjust some parts of the `context`.

You can use `task` module in springXD to do `ETL`

Comment: Thanks Abner for your response. Well, I have a slightly different use case.